# MySQL function to format time in SQL query as mm:ss

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

MySQL NOOB having issues...

I have a column in my database called TotalTime which stores elapsed time (hh:mm:ss).  In the table it is stored as type = time.

When it is displayed it shows hh:mm:ss.  Thus, 3:55 displays as 00:03:55.

In my SQL query is there a way to format to show 03:55 (or better yet 3:55)?

Beginning of query looks like:

```
SELECT
    OverallRank,
    First,
    Last,
    TotalTime,
    AgeGroup...
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
i for minutes
s for seconds
```

like--  `i:s`

```
%i  Minutes, numeric (00..59)
%s  Seconds (00..59)
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT OverallRank, First, Last, DATE_FORMAT(TotalTime, "%i:%s") as TotalTime,...
FROM tbl_name
```

Comment: posting how the OP would implement this into their query would be very helpful. :)

Comment: @bluefeet i was thinking the same to do it in my edit, but found most people already posted the code before im going to post this edited code :)

Comment: Understandable, but you were first to post so expanding on your answer would be good.

Comment: @bluefeet done sir, thx for making me to follow the standards :)

Comment: @bluefeet i thought he was looking for minutes and seconds, but he accepted answer for hours and minutes ..my bad :)

Comment: Thank you very much. However... How do i get the column head to remain TotalTime and not show up as DATE_FORMAT(TotalTime, "%i:%s")

Comment: @chris use `DATE_FORMAT(TotalTime, "%i:%s") as TotalTime`...give it an alias

Answer (score 2):

You can prehaps use DATE_FORMAT()? 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
SELECT OverallRank, First, Last, DATE_FORMAT(TotalTime, "%i:%s") as TotalTime, AgeGroup..
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  However... How do i get the column head to remain TotalTime and not show up as DATE_FORMAT(TotalTime, "%H:%i")

Answer (score 0):

Check the [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

You can do something like:

```
SELECT
    OverallRank,
    First,
    Last,
    DATE_FORMAT(TotalTime, '%i:%s'),
    AgeGroup...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain your `3:55` output rather than `03:55` you can also use an [**IF**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) construct:

```
SELECT OverallRank, 
       First, 
       Last, 
       IF (LEFT(DATE_FORMAT(TotalTime, "%i:%s"),1) == '0',     #IF
                SUBSTRING(DATE_FORMAT(TotalTime, "%i:%s"),2) , #yes part
                DATE_FORMAT(TotalTime, "%i:%s")) as TotalTime, #no part
       AgeGroup..
```